# Return reference from class to this

Tags: c++, reference, return, this

I have the following member of class foo.

```
foo &foo::bar()
{
   return this;
}
```

But I am getting compiler errors. What stupid thing am I doing wrong?

Compiler error (gcc): error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'foo&' from a temporary of type 'foo* const'

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`this` is a pointer. So it should be `return *this;`

Answer (score 8):

As Naveen points out, you need to return `*this`.

Just a quick tip though: a way to figure out what somewhat obscure compiler errors mean is to try compiling on a different compiler to see if there is a better message. For example, you can use [Comeau online](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout).

In this case it gives:

```
"ComeauTest.c", line 7: error: initial value of reference to non-const must be an
          lvalue
     return this;
            ^
```

Not sure it's better in this case - but in some cases the messages are way better.

Comment: indeed, MSVC 2008 returns, "error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'foo *const ' to 'foo &'", which I think is pretty clear.